# Convert byte array containing small numbers (1-30) to string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte

as the title specfies I'm trying to convert a byte array to string.
with no luck.
say my byte array is: [11,20,9].

```
(I've entered: array[0] = 11; array[1] = 20;...)
String str;
str = array.toString(); // prints: [B@4554617c
```

When I try using str = new String(array) I get some weird symbols.

Any you of familiar with a method for this case?
thanks.

Comment: use the `String` constructor. Something like this: `new String(array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: thank you, I'll look it up.

Comment: `String str = Arrays.toString(array);`
(because in Java, arrays are _very_ dumb)